# Random movement avoiding walls

Tags: java

I have a top-down game you can scroll through placeable tiles I have some NPCs that do nothing at the moment I want them to freely move around without going through wall tiles etc.

For the freely moving I have code and it works fine but they walk through walls:

```
if(new Random().nextInt(4) == 0){
   x+=1;
}
if(new Random().nextInt(4) == 1){
   x-=1;
}
if(new Random().nextInt(4) == 2){
   y+=1;
}
if(new Random().nextInt(4) == 3){
   y-=1;
}
```

How can I make it so they don't walk through walls?

All the solid tiles are stored in an arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<block> s = new ArrayList<block>();
```

and then have the `for` loops for them and each block has its own rectangle around it.

Comment: Are none of the answers below suitable for you? You should provide feedback if they're not or accept the answer most useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't check if the NPCs are colliding with a block, there are two things you could do:

1. Check if the tile the NPC want to move on is solid.
2. Move the NPC, then check if they are standing on a solid block, if yes then move back.

I would suggest method one, so you could do something like that:

```
int r = random.nextInt(4);
if(r == 0 && validMove(x+1,y)){
   x += 1;
}
if(r == 1 && validMove(x-1,y)){
   x -= 1;
}
if(r == 2 && validMove(x,y+1)){
   y += 1;
}
if(r == 3 && validMove(x,y-1)){
   y -= 1;
}
```

So they will only move if they will be on a valid position.
`validMove(x,y)` could look like the following code:

If your `ArrayList` is sorted you could try this:

```
boolean validMove(int x, int y) {
    Block b = s.get((x-1) + (y-1)*mapWidth);
    if(b.getX() == x && b.getY() == y) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

How does that work? Let's do a simple example, imagine you have an `ArrayList` with following coordinates:

```
{(1,1);(2,1);(3,1);(4,1);
 (1,2);(2,2);(3,2);(4,2);
 (1,3);(2,3);(3,3);(4,3)}
```

We have `mapWidth = 4` and `mapHeight = 3`.
So now you have `x = 2` and `y = 3`, you should get `(2,3)` which is at `Index 9`.
The calculation is `i = (2-1) + (3-1) * 4 = 1 + 2 * 4 = 1 + 8 = 9`.

Else you can do it like this (almost similar to [Byte56 answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/71311/42265)), but there you wouldn't have fast access if the map is big.

```
boolean validMove(int x, int y) {
    for(Block b : s) {
        if(b.getX() == x && b.getY() == y) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For method 2 you could use intersection checks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some kind of `isSolid(x,y)` function. Unfortunately you're storing all your blocks in an array list, so it's going to be difficult to do this in a fast way, but that's up to you to figure out.

Once you have your `isSolid(x,y)` function, you can modify your code like:

```
if(!isSolid(x+1, y) && new Random().nextInt(4) == 0){
   x+=1;
}
//etc.
```

A naive approach to your `isSolid` function can be:

```
boolean isSolid(int x, int y) {
    for(Block b : s) {
      if(b.x == x && b.y == y)
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I'd suggest you place your blocks into a 2D array (or a 1D array with the index specified by the x,y). If you have your blocks in a 2D array you can easily check `blocks[x][y].solid` or something similar, instead of looping through all your blocks.

Alternatively you can use the rectangles in your scene for collision detection, where your `isSolid(x,y)` function would do a collision check at that position.